# Where is wide.launch in stereo_image_proc package?

Tags: stere-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [Stereo Processing in Simulation](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/UsingStereoProcessingInSimulation).

I run:

```
  roslaunch gazebo_worlds simple_world.launch
  roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2.launch
```

Then I run:

```
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/test$ roslaunch stereo_image_proc wide.launch
  cannot locate [wide.launch] in package [stereo_image_proc]
  ira@ira-K42JP:~/code/ros/test$
```

Where is wide.launch?

Or what's the substitute?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40626/where-is-wide.launch-in-stereo_image_proc-package?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the confusion, I may delete the tutorial as the [stereo_image_procs](http://ros.org/wiki/stereo_image_proc) are started by default when you

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
```

But, you can look in the [dual stereo camera launch file](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_simulator/trunk/pr2_gazebo/config/dualstereo_camera.launch) and find the nodes that starts up the stereo image proc nodes.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0